# How to return a value on a ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have created a function that when called it renders me a react component in the dom with certain props and functionalities.

When rendering this component an asynchronous call is made to an API and a message is displayed on the screen, everything works perfectly. The problem is that I don't know how to return the response from this asynchronous call and not just render the element since I want to access this data directly. And not having to use a "storage" function with useEffect to save that response, I want to detect when the message is received and that I think would only be possible by making that asynchronous call but I have no idea how to implement it.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/ClipLoader";
import "./happi.css";
import axios from "axios";
import objectPath from "object-path";

// Definimos la animacion entrante y saliente
const happiAnim = {
  show: {
    y: 0,
  },
  hide: {
    y: 200,
  },
};

// Componente de React
function Compo(props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false); // Variable inicial
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false); // Mostrar u ocultar componente
  const [data, setData] = useState({ name: "Hola" }); // Data Inicial

  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);

  const [apiStatus, setApiStatus] = useState("loading"); // Status de la llamada

  // Cargamos la data inicial
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loaded) {
      if (props.config) {
        setData(props.config);
      }
      setLoaded(true);
      setShow(true);

      // Minimo de tiempo de carga para animacion de LOADING definida aqui
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoad(true);
      }, 700);

      // Mostramos data cargada

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };

      if (props.method === "post") {
        axios
          .post(props.url, props.data, config)
          .then((res) => {
            setData({
              status: res.status,
              message: objectPath.get(res, props.rSelector),
              response: res,
            });
            ocultarModal(objectPath.get(res, props.rSelector), res.status);
            props.storage(res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setData({
              status: err.status,
              message: err.response.message,
              response: err,
            });
          });
      } else {
        axios
          .get(props.url)
          .then((res) => {
            setData({
              status: res.status,
              message: objectPath.get(res, props.rSelector),
              response: res,
            });
            ocultarModal(objectPath.get(res, props.rSelector), res.status);
            props.storage(res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setData({
              status: err.status,
              message: err.response.message,
              response: err,
            });
          });
      }

      const ocultarModal = (message, status) => {
        setApiStatus(status);

        // Medimos el string para calcular el tiempo de muestra del modal
        let len = message.length;

        // Ocultamos
        setTimeout(() => {
          setShow(false);
        }, len * 50);

        // Ocultamos
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById("happimodal").remove();
        }, len * 51);
      };
    }
  });

  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={happiAnim}
      initial="hide"
      animate={loaded && show ? "show" : "hide"}
      className="happimodal"
    >
      <div className="happimodal__iconContainer">
        {apiStatus !== "loading" && load ? (
          data.message
        ) : (
          <ClipLoader loading={true} size={15} />
        )}
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

// Funcion inicial
export function Happi(
  url,
  responseSelector = "data",
  storage,
  data = {},
  method = "get"
) {
  let element = document.createElement("div");
  element.setAttribute("id", "happimodal");
  element.classList.add("happicontainer");

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Compo
      url={url}
      data={data}
      method={method}
      rSelector={responseSelector}
      storage={storage}
    />,
    document.body.appendChild(element)
  );
}
```

Then I use the function like this

```
import "./App.css";
import { Happi } from "./components/happi";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [apiRes, setApiRes] = useState({});

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            Happi(
              "https://some-random-api.ml/facts/panda",
              "data.fact",
              setApiRes
            )
          }
        >
          A ver
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => console.log(apiRes)}>Mostrar res</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but I would like to save the data in the return of the function, so then i can use maybe this

```
console.log(Happi("https://some-random-api.ml/facts/panda", "data.fact", setApiRes))
```

And it returns me the object of the response

Answer (score 0):

A few things, avoid doing stuff like this when using React

```
  let element = document.createElement("div");
  element.setAttribute("id", "happimodal");
  element.classList.add("happicontainer");
```

Also you can't use `const [apiRes, setApiRes] = useState({});` outside a component

Also you can't use ReactDom.render inside a component

Here's some code that kind of does what you want, but I took out a few node modules

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import axios from "axios";
import objectPath from "object-path";

// Definimos la animacion entrante y saliente
const happiAnim = {
  show: {
    y: 0
  },
  hide: {
    y: 200
  }
};

// Componente de React
function Compo(props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false); // Variable inicial
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false); // Mostrar u ocultar componente
  const [data, setData] = useState({ name: "Hola" }); // Data Inicial

  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);

  const [apiStatus, setApiStatus] = useState("loading"); // Status de la llamada

  // Cargamos la data inicial
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loaded) {
      if (props.config) {
        setData(props.config);
      }
      setLoaded(true);
      setShow(true);

      // Minimo de tiempo de carga para animacion de LOADING definida aqui
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoad(true);
      }, 700);

      // Mostramos data cargada

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      };

      if (props.method === "post") {
        axios
          .post(props.url, props.data, config)
          .then((res) => {
            setData({
              status: res.status,
              message: objectPath.get(res, props.rSelector),
              response: res
            });
            ocultarModal(objectPath.get(res, props.rSelector), res.status);
            props.storage(res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setData({
              status: err.status,
              message: err.message,
              response: err
            });
          });
      } else {
        axios
          .get(props.url)
          .then((res) => {
            setData({
              status: res.status,
              message: objectPath.get(res, props.rSelector),
              response: res
            });
            ocultarModal(objectPath.get(res, props.rSelector), res.status);
            props.storage(res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setData({
              status: err.status,
              message: err.message,
              response: err
            });
          });
      }

      const ocultarModal = (message, status) => {
        setApiStatus(status);

        // Medimos el string para calcular el tiempo de muestra del modal
        let len = message.length;

        // Ocultamos
        setTimeout(() => {
          setShow(false);
        }, len * 50);

        // Ocultamos
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById("happimodal").remove();
        }, len * 51);
      };
    }
  });

  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={happiAnim}
      initial="hide"
      animate={loaded && show ? "show" : "hide"}
      className="happimodal"
    >
      <div className="happimodal__iconContainer">
        {apiStatus !== "loading" && load ? (
          data.message
        ) : (
          <p>There would be a clip loader here </p>
        )}
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}

// Funcion inicial
const Happi = (
  url,
  responseSelector = "data",
  storage,
  data = {},
  method = "get"
) => {
  return (
    <div id="happimodal" className="happicontainer">
      <Compo
        url={url}
        data={data}
        method={method}
        rSelector={responseSelector}
        storage={storage}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Happi />, rootElement);
```

---

You can see the [code on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-goldberg-upkrl?file=/src/index.js:0-3565), start a new sandbox to see a hello world react program with ReactDom in the right place. I put it all in one file in this example to match your code more closely

Comment: Thank you so much!! i will try it, i tried to run it on codesandbox but i get and error. Will take a look to the code

Comment: I didnt see the diference there and i cant get the values in the return. I didnt used useState outside a component, it was just for not uploading all the code. Please take a look at my edit an my app.js file code

Comment: IT works perfectly, also i get the response saved in the state of my APP, the problem is that i need to get that data from the Happi() function directly

Comment: So i dont have to check if the state changed, and then store the data in another place. I want to do it with a promise, so when the function is called

Comment: It will wait the component inside, do an axios api call and then when it got the data. Return it in the function